# Tag synonym found (I think)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I think these are tag synonyms:

- [comparison](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison)
- [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference)

They basically do the same thing, but not mean the same thing. You get the difference through comparison. I think they should be tag synonyms.

Comment: It's a bit problematic when a meta post explicitly advocates a specific course of action. I want to ***upvote*** because this is an important issue, but I want to ***downvote*** because I don't think OP's proposed "tag merge" is the right thing to do. It would be better if the OP had asked *"Should we do something about [tag:comparison] and [tag:difference]" tags?"*, and posted his own suggestion as an answer we could all vote on. Votes for/against the question itself would then more clearly indicate whether people care about doing *anything* in this area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, I think some of the questions tagged [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) should have been tagged [comparison](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison), but they serve different purposes; as a first thought, [comparison](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison) can actually refer to questions about words that refer to *comparison*.

However, as it is, the tag descriptions are unclear, and perhaps we should be editing the questions to identify those that should have [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference) tags instead. It really depends on the perspective, but they're not the same thing in the end; maybe just a tag description edit will suffice.

On the other hand, there are so few questions tagged [comparison](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison) anyway, so just quickly, I think there are only a couple of questions I can find where it wouldn't be appropriate to re-tag as [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference):

- [Comparison with a hypothetical](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11273/comparison-with-a-hypothetical)
- [What does "ever" mean in comparative constructions?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/13476/what-does-ever-mean-in-comparative-constructions)

I'll leave it to the mods and the community, though, but I don't think they're synonymous.

Comment: Personally, I would rather have [tag:differences] and either [tag:comparatives] or [tag:comparative-constructions] or such.

Comment: @snail yeah, that seems like a reasonable change; I think people are defaulting to [tag:comparison] because they're comparing, rather than because the question is about [tag:comparatives], which IMO is closer to the spirit o f the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I think we've got something of a [use–mention distinction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Use%E2%80%93mention_distinction) here. We need to distinguish...

> 1: questions asking for the ***difference*** between two or more *alternative* ways of expressing something
>    2: questions about usages involving ***comparison*** (e.g. - *metaphors, similes*)
>    3: questions about the use of ***comparatives*** and ***superlatives*** (such as *better, worst*)

Personally, I'd be in favour of using the above highlighted words for those particular senses So far as I'm concerned, the (currently, 31) existing instances of [comparison](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparison) should thus be *re-tagged* [difference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/difference).